# How can I replace option values inside of ul class list?

Tags: javascript

how can I replace these values inside of this "ul class list" with JS?

I am trying something like :

```
document.getElementById("option1").options.item(0).text = "newName";
```

[image: list values]

Comment: I don't see a `#option1` element anywhere. Also you can't just make up your own syntax for this.

Comment: what i need to type instead #option1 to get the pointed list, this is my question

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelectorAll(".list > li")[0].innerHTML = "newName"
```